# C#: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I am getting an error as shown in the title. I have no idea why im getting this or as to how im supposed to fix this. Visual Studio is giving me the error shown in the title on this line: var f = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fil1);

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        string fil1 = "C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\Jobboppgave\CaseConsoleApp\Prisfile.txt";

        ***var f = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fil1);***
        int length = (int)(new System.IO.FileInfo(fil1).Length);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your path is incorrect because you didn't escape `\` in it. The fastest way to do it is using `@`:

```
string fil1 = @"C:\Users\mariu\Desktop\Jobboppgave\CaseConsoleApp\Prisfile.txt";
```

Rebuild your project and problem will be resolved.

Comment: Just to show the alternative, you can also write: `string fil1 = "C:\\Users\\mariu\\Desktop\\Jobboppgave\\CaseConsoleApp\\Prisfile.txt";`