# The filename, directory name or volume label is incorrect

Tags: c#, error-handling, azure-blob-storage

this is my code and i get an error that the filename/ directory is incorrect. The file does exist in that directory. I want to upload this file to my azure blob storage.

```
private static void UploadFileToBlobStorage()
    {
        var localFilePath = "C:\\Users\\LK\\source\repos\dsd-ica-perf\\src\\et.ure.ica.Perf\\PerfTest.cs";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnStr);

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("perfTest");

        Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobServiceClient.Uri);

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("PerfTest");

        using FileStream uploadingFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);

        blobClient.Upload(uploadingFileStream);
        uploadingFileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: the line `var localFilePath = "C:\\Users\\LK\\source\repos\dsd-ica-perf\\src\\et.ure.ica.Perf\\PerfTest.cs";` should be `var localFilePath = "C:\\Users\\LK\\source\\repos\\dsd-ica-perf\\src\\et.ure.ica.Perf\\PerfTest.cs";` or `var localFilePath = @"C:\Users\LK\source\repos\dsd-ica-perf\src\et.ure.ica.Perf\PerfTest.cs";`

Comment: The code you posted doesn't actually compile. It will give you "Unrecognised escape sequence" because of the "\d" in "repos\dsd". For this reason, I suspect that you're not giving us the whole story.

Comment: Are you the user LK?  Only an admin or user has access to the folder.  When inside VS you do not have admin privilege's unless you start VS from shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Yes I'm the user LK

Comment: I tried using both strings 
"C:\\Users\\LK\\source\\repos\\dsd-ica-perf\\src\\et.ure.ica.Perf\\PerfTest.cs";
and
@"C:\Users\LK\source\repos\dsd-ica-perf\src\et.ure.ica.Perf\PerfTest.cs";                 But now I get different error that the specified resource name contains invalid characters

Comment: This is because you are using "perfTest" as the blob container name. Blob container name should be all lowercase. Please try with "perftest".

Answer (score 0):

***When I have tried with above code I was able to upload a file successfully in azure blob storage"***

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace blobstorage
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var storageConnStr = <connection string of the storage account>;
            var localFilePath = "@"C:\root"; #path of the folder which should be upto file
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageConnStr);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container1");#lowercase should be allowed.

            Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobServiceClient.Uri);

            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("folder1");

            using FileStream uploadingFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);

            blobClient.Upload(uploadingFileStream);
            uploadingFileStream.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

***Azure portal -> storage account:*** Before uploading a file.

[image]

***Output:***
[image]

[image]

When i tried with above code I uploaded a file successfully in azure blob storage.

[image]

As said by @gauravmantri in comment the blob container name should be in lowercase and the error occurs due to path of folder is wrong condition.kindly check above code the path should be in that way.

**Reference:**

[system.io.file - C#: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686917/c-system-io-directorynotfoundexception-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path) by ingvar